# Onmouse over not working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Below is my code which highlights the `Download` button when I move the mouse over that button. But after clicking the Download button, corresponding action takes place and when I closed the prompt window, and on moving the cursor  again over the download button, it fails to treat it as link. That is it fails to show the hand cursor. Cursor appears as a single vertical bar. (ie, cursor in the edit text box)

```
<div class="seemorebutto" style="margin-left: 72px;">
    <%--<a href="#" class="button nineteen" style="color: White;">--%>
    <a href='<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"].ToString() %>/LandingPage/Medeil/MTrialEdition.aspx' class="button nineteen1" onclick="loadwindow(this,event);" style="color: White;">
    <i class="icon-right-circled"></i><b>Download</b></a></div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[Link to the site](http://www.vanuston.com/) . See at the bottom.

```
function loadwindow(obj,e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href=$(obj).attr("href");
        var item=$(obj).attr("id");
        $('#Iframe1').hide();
        $('#Iframe1').show();
        $('.frame1').show();
        var holdyDiv = $('<div class="inframe-lo-backdrop"></div>').attr('id', 'holdy');
        holdyDiv.appendTo('body');
       $('#Iframe1').attr('src', href+"?item="+item);
        $('#Iframe1').attr('style', 'width:60%;');
    }
////    
////   function loadwin(obj,e)
////  {
////        e.preventDefault();
////        var href=$(obj).attr("href");
////        var item=$(obj).attr("id");
////       $('#frameload').hide();
////        $('#frameload').show();
////        $('.frame').show();
////       $('.bg-pop').show();
////        var holdyDiv = $('<div class="inframe-lo-backdrop"></div>').attr('id', 'holdy');
////        holdyDiv.appendTo('body');
////       $('#frameload').attr('src', href);
////       $('#frameload').attr('style', 'width:60%;');
////   }

   function closeme()
    {
       $('.frame1').hide();
        $('#Iframe1').attr('src', '');
        $('.inframe-lo-backdrop').hide();
    }
```

Css Code:

```
.inframe-lo,.frame1{
    border:none;
    height:inherit;
    position:fixed;
    min-height:650px;
    opacity:1;
    left:20%;
    right:20%;
    top:5%;
    bottom:0%;
    display:block;
    z-index:99999;
}
.inframe-lo-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #000;
}
.inframe-lo-backdrop{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.inframe-lo-backdrop.fade {
    opacity: 0;
}
a.closebbtn{
    font-size: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 34.9%;
    display: inline-table;
    float: right;
    float: left;
    color:#000;
    top: 40px;
    border: solid 1px #EEE;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 999999;
}
a.closebbtn:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:#0287CC;
    border: solid 0px #EEE;
    cursor:default;
}
```

Comment: Can you post loadwindow()?

Comment: Just tested on chrome (v44), it works for me

Comment: @AhsN same result here! It works fine.

Comment: Why don't you start trying to fix errors in console?

Comment: You have javascript errors , probably that errors make it to stop from working in some cases.

Comment: please  wait sir @SzabolcsPáll

Comment: @AhsN : I was able to reproduce the error. Try the above mentioned steps with the button in second column.

Comment: the issue is, after opening it and closing the popup, there is an element which is sitting on top of the download button and receiving the clicks

Comment: [Link to the site](http://www.vanuston.com/)

Comment: How to solve this problem sir @CerlinBoss

Comment: it must be an issue with z-index. but i am not sure where it is. When you get the cursor change right click and check the inspect element, which will take you to the element which is taking all the clicks.

Comment: i dont meet this, everything working (chrome)

Comment: Not working sir just click one time again you clink that time not working properly sir@kobe

Comment: i will try sir @CerlinBoss

Answer (score -3):

Use hover state to do this in a separate css stylesheet :
in your html:

In your css :

```
.download-btn {
        cursor: hand;
    }

    .download-btn:hover {
        background-color: #yourcolorcode;
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't need pseudo class `:hover` regarding cursor property

Comment: the issue is not with the cursor. after opening it and  closing the popup, there is an element which is sitting on top of the download button and receiving the clicks

Comment: then it's because he don't remove the popup properly, or he didn't put it in `position absolute` with `z-index`

Comment: the actual element which is getting the click is not from the popup i guess.